# Problema con posiciones de elementos HTML

Tags: jquery, html, html5, css, css3

Tengo dos páginas: En la primera tengo los elementos en un contenedor que al guardarlos en la BD se cargan en la segunda página.

En la segunda página, estos elementos se cargan directamente en el body, el problema que tengo es que la relación de distancia en ambas páginas es distinta o no sé cómo corregirla.

[image: Problema con Divs]

Básicamente uso la primera página con [jQuery UI](https://api.jqueryui.com/) para hacer a los elementos [draggable](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) y con `.position()` saco sus distancias en relación a sus elementos padre (en el primer caso el `div` más grande, en el segundo, el `body`).

Sé que el `.offset()` es para sacar la distancia con respecto al documento y que `.position()` es para sacarla con respecto al elemento padre.

¿Ideas de cómo hacerlo correlativo?

**Edición #1:**

Como guardo las posiciones de los elementos en la primera página:

```
$('#documento').draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        dragged = true;
        args.documento.top = $(this).position().top + 'px';
        args.documento.left = $(this).position().left + 'px';
    }
});
```

Como cargo las posiciones de los elementos en la segunda página:

```
#documento { 
    top: {{ number_format($posiciones['documento']['top'], 2) . "px;" }}
    left: {{ number_format($posiciones['documento']['left'], 2) . "px;" }}
}
```

**Edición #2:**

Para ver en tiempo real lo que hacen las páginas:

[Enlace a la primera página](http://www.efactura.online/configuracion/factura)

[Enlace a la segunda página](http://www.efactura.online/test/pdf/6)

***Pueden notar que incluso si recargan la primera página después de guardar las posiciones, las posiciones se cargan "mal".***

**Edición #4:**
A pedido de @Shaz, subo el código backend:

Con éste guardo las posiciones, utilizo el framework Laravel:

```
public function guardarPosiciones (Request $request)
{
    $posicion = Posiciones::first();

    if(!isset($posicion->id))
    {
        $posicion = new Posiciones;
    }

    $input = $request->all();

    foreach($input as $k => $v)
    {
        $top = $k . 'Top';
        $left = $k . 'Left';

        $posicion->$top = $v['top'];
        $posicion->$left = $v['left'];
    }

    $posicion->save();
}
```

Y con éste tomo las posiciones:

```
public function factura ()
{
    $posiciones = \App\Posiciones::first();

    $data['posiciones'] = $posiciones;

    return view('conf.factura', $data);
}
```

Y con éste último, como mencioné anteriormente, lo asigno en la vista:

```
#documento { 
    top: {{ number_format($posiciones['documento']['top'], 2) . "px;" }}
    left: {{ number_format($posiciones['documento']['left'], 2) . "px;" }}
}
```

En caso de que no se entienda, el [number_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) es para mostrar el valor float con dos números después de la coma en el siguiente criterio:

```
@if ($factura->documento)
    <p class="draggable" id="documento">{!! $factura->documento !!}</p>
    <p class="draggable" id="documento-copia">{!! $factura->documento !!}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: ¿Guardas también las distancias que hay entre los elementos en la primera página? ¿O quieres poner la relación igual que en la primera pero a mano, es decir, directamente en el css?

Comment: @Error404, guardo las distancias que hay sólamente para la segunda página, se suponía que debía haber la misma distancia con el elemento padre en ambas páginas. Y al cargarlas en la primera página se ven diferente.

Comment: Me refiero, ¿las guardas en la base de datos? ¿O las pones directamente en la segunda página?

Comment: Lo guardo en la base de datos y los cargo con PHP

Comment: Puede validar que la distancia que se guarda en la DB es correcta? Podrías agregar algo de código para que podamos entender mejor como se muestras los `div` en el body?

Comment: Agregué código... Las coordenadas con correctas. He probado también con `margin`.

Comment: ¿por qué estaría mal el código generado @MarcosGallardo?

Comment: @MarcosGallardo, ¿qué está mal? Sustituye todo lo contenido dentro y las llaves mismas de `{{ ... }}` por un número cualquiera.

Comment: @Maramal necesitamos ver un ejemplo más "real" o algún código que podamos probar, por ahora considero que falta información. Tal vez un ejemplo que incluya por un lado un la primera parte (incluyendo jQuery UI) y un ejemplo de la segunda (solo HTML y CSS, poniendo como datos de entrada el css ya generado).

Comment: @Shaz, edité el post, y puse para hacer pruebas.

Comment: Gracias, ya empiezo a entender, ¿podemos ver el código con el cual tomas TODAS las posiciones y la parte backend (PHP) con la que las procesas y guardas en la base de datos?

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Gracias por añadir la información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error radica en que en la primer pagina, todos los `p` están en `position: relative`. En cambio, en la segunda página estan en `position: absolute`.

> Al utilizar `.position()` sobre `p` posicionados **relativamente al padre y entre si**, las coordenas devueltas serán distintas que si los `p` estuvieran posicionados absolutamente. Es por esta razón que al visualizarlos en la segunda página **aparecen en otro lugar**

La solución simple:

> - En la primer pagina, cambiar todos los `p` a `position: absolute`.
>
>   Lo malo de hacer esto es que todos los `p` inicialmente se solaparan, lo cual volverá engorroso buscar y mover el `p` indicado. Pero solo la primera vez.

Una solución un poco mas rebuscada:

> - Modificar la `position` de los `p` tras ser `dragged` por primera vez.
>
>   **Nota:** En la primer página cuando posicionas los `p` movidos, no debes olvidarte también posicionarlos `absolute`. De no hacerlo, parecera que estan mal posicionados

```
$('#documento').draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        dragged = true;
        // Modificas la position tras el primer drag
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        args.documento.top = $(this).position().top + 'px';
        args.documento.left = $(this).position().left + 'px';
    }
});
```

Comment: La función `.position()` funciona correctamente. De todas formas estás aconsejando que cambie la posición al mover los elementos, no al iniciar el documento.

Comment: Asi es, ya que si la cambias desde el principio todos los `p` se solaparan

Comment: Los elementos tienen la función `.draggable()` por lo que puedes arrastrarlos con el mouse...

Comment: Considera realizar la siguiente prueba. Ve a la primer pagina. Mueve 1 elemento. Guardar. Refresca. Veras que no esta donde lo dejaste. Eso es porque `.position()` no esta devolviendo las mismas coordenas que si el `p` estuviera en `position: absolute`.

Comment: Bueno... prueba y me dices, hice lo que me dijiste.

Comment: Como es de suponerse, mientras mantienes el clic presionado, el elemento es reubicado al comenzar el contenedor padre.

Comment: En la primer pagina, estaría faltando que al recargar y setear las coordenadas guardadas, agregar a los `p` movidos `position: absolute`